# How to prove that $ \int_0^1 \frac{e^x}{x+1}dx\le \frac e2$ using the inner product.

Tags: definite-integrals, inner-products, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Let

$$\langle f,g \rangle=\displaystyle\int_0^1f(t)g(t)dt$$ be an inner product over $C[0,1]$. How to prove that

$$\displaystyle\int_0^1 \dfrac{e^x}{x+1}dx\le \dfrac e2$$

My miserable work: by Cauchy-Schwarz inequality $|\langle f,g \rangle|\le \|f\|\cdot\|g\|$, and if we were to take $f=e^x$, $g=1/(x+1)$ , observe that $f,g\in C[0,1]$

$$\displaystyle\int_0^1 \dfrac{e^x}{x+1}dx\le \sqrt{\displaystyle\int_0^1 e^{2x}dx} \sqrt{\displaystyle\int_0^1 \dfrac{1}{(x+1)^2}dx}=\sqrt{\frac{1}{2e^2}-\frac{1}{2}}\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}\le \frac{e}{2}$$

Comment: Good work!  One correction: remove square root from LHS of last inequality.

Comment: Your work is not miserable at all. Not sure about the linear algebra tag though!

Comment: $\int_0^1 \dfrac{e^x}{x+1}dx < \tfrac12+\tfrac{\mathrm e}4$
due to the convexity of the integrand on $[0,1]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to 
[convexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function)
of the integrand on $[0,1]$,

\begin{align} 
\int_0^1 \dfrac{\exp(x)}{x+1}dx 
&<
\int_0^1 \Big((\tfrac{\mathrm{e}}2-1)\,x+1 \Big) \, dx
=\frac12+\frac{\mathrm e}4
<\frac{\mathrm e}2
.
\end{align}

And if you like, you can write

\begin{align} 
\int_0^1 \Big((\tfrac{\mathrm{e}}2-1)\,x+1 \Big) \, dx
&\le
\sqrt{\int_0^1 1\,dx}
\cdot
\sqrt{\int_0^1 \Big((\tfrac{\mathrm{e}}2-1)\,x+1 \Big)^2 \, dx}
\\
&=\frac16\,\sqrt{3\,\mathrm{e}^2+6\,\mathrm{e}+12}
<\frac{\mathrm e}2
.
\end{align}